# Relating collision theory to rate of reaction

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics

I want to relate the macroscopic advancement of a reaction, the rate of the reaction, with the microscopic collisions of the molecules. This is the type I have developed so far:

$$u = A^2 \times \frac{n_1}{m^2} \times\frac{n_2}{m^2}\times \frac{(m_1u_1^2+m_2u_2^2)}{E_\mathrm{act}}\times 1/t $$

where $u$ is the rate of reaction in $\pu{mol2 sec-1}$.

$A =$ the common area of the substances

$n_1/m^2 =$ the moles per square metre of the first substance

$n_2/m^2 =$ the moles per square meter of the second substance

$u_1$ and $u_2 =$ average velocity of molecules of each substance

$E_\mathrm{act} =$ activation energy of the reaction

Now the molecules of the first substance must bump to the molecules of the second substance with the appropriate orientation. How can I add this to my type?

Comment: Please use mathJax formatting for variables and equations. I formatted your equation, but unsure of the content you intended to. Please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: Reaction velocity cannot be $\pu{mol \cdot s}$ anyway. So, I corrected accordingly. If you are not comfortable with my edit, you may change it as you want, but I warn you, this would be questioned by others. :-)

Comment: It is ok.I will add a constant which will give the correct units of measure.

Comment: @BrightFuture To my present knowledge, despite the time-dependent advancement of a reaction of a reaction is subject of (chemical) kinetics, the English term you search is either «rate of reaction» (http://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/R05156) or «reaction rate». On  the other hand, your thought of line is very close to the concept of collision theory, the (effective) cross-section of moving molecules is an important parameter.  See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_theory.  This may justfiy rewording the title of the question.

Comment: I know what collision theory is.

Comment: This is an interesting question and many experimental method exist to study it. For more information have a look at 'Chemical Kinetics and Dynamics' by Steinfeld, Francisco & Hase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is interesting to see you creating your own approach. The comments above provide good responses. I would recommend looking at Buttonwoods suggestion regarding collision theory and cross-sections. However, it appears none have answered your question directly, so I will provide my response to it here.

**Question:** *"Now the molecules of the first substance must bump to the molecules of the second substance with the appropriate orientation. How can I add this to my type?"*

**My Response:** You recognize that orientation is important when it comes to chemical reactions. There are many ways to handle this, I will provide three short suggestions and you can consider them or use them to come up with something else.

*Arrhenius (constant) approach:* The pre-exponential factor, $\alpha$, in the following Arrhenius equation absorbs two important concepts of chemical reactivity - 1) the frequency of collisions, 2) the orientation of the molecules.

$$u = \alpha e^{-E_a/RT}$$

Note, I changed from the conventional notation in order to match and not confuse with your own. In fact, $\alpha$ is defined as the frequency of properly oriented collisions. So a simple constant multiplier that accounts for orientation can help modify your equation.

*Boolean logic:* You can possibly simplify things further by using a simple selection function that tells you whether the molecules are in proper orientation. Here is the simplest you could use:

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 \text{ if proper orientation}\\
0 \text{ if not proper orientation}
\end{cases}$$

*Functional dependence:* Last mentioned here would be the most creative approach to come up with a function that describes the orientation of your molecules. You will have to come up with the functional dependencies you need (i.e. a reaction coordinate) to help solve your problem. Here is an example of a reaction between atomic hydrogen with molecular hydrogen to make the same species using sinusoidal function where the independent variable (reaction coordinate) is the angle of the H-H bond relative to the hydrogen atom.

$$\text{Reaction:    } H-H + H^{\boldsymbol{\cdot}} \to H^{\boldsymbol{\cdot}} + H-H$$
$$\text{Function:    } f(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)+1\right]$$

[image]

The interpretation of such a function as this would be 100% likely to react if the $H$ atom is in the plane of the bond with $H_2$ while 0% likely to react if $H_2$ is vertical. This isn't an exact reality, but just an example.